# where to catch the exception in a "for" loop?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have some code used to parse XML which I want to improve a bit (mainly to account for malformed XML files).

```
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

context = ET.iterparse("myfile.xml", events=("start", "end"))
context = iter(context)
event, root = context.next()
for event, elem in context:
    if event == 'start' and elem.tag == "hello":
        print("start report")
```

It works fine with this valid XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Report name="TEST" xmlns:cm="http://www.nessus.org/cm">
<hello>world</hello>
</Report>
```

If I invalidate the XML by removing the last tag I get a `SyntaxError` exception, which is what I want to catch to handle invalid XML

The traceback from the run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/GetNessusScans/parsereport.py", line 12, in <module>
    for event, elem in context:
  File "<string>", line 68, in __iter__
SyntaxError: no element found: line 4, column 0
```

**My question is: where should I place the `try:` to catch this exception?**

I need to parse the file linearly because of its size and my understanding is that the `for` loop eventually gets to a point where there is a missing tag (or a mismatched one). I tried some exotic code (the `except` clause will actually do something useful, this is just a test):

```
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

context = ET.iterparse("myfile.xml", events=("start", "end"))
context = iter(context)
event, root = context.next()
try:
    for event, elem in context:
except SyntaxError:
    print("invalid XML")
else:
    # if we hit the description of the scan, save it
    if event == 'start' and elem.tag == "hello":
        print("start report")
```

but as I suspected it is not correct.

Comment: Why would you want to parse invalid xml? It's impossible by definition to properly parse an invalid file.

Comment: @ch3ka: Some of the XML files I will get may be broken, I only want to be able to discard them

Comment: then you should wrap the whole parsing in `try: except:`, as mu answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bring the whole parsing block within a fresh `try - except` block. The rationale being, that any tag could be broken in your XML, not just the last one, and so the error may occur anywhere in the parsing.

```
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
try:
    context = ET.iterparse("myfile.xml", events=("start", "end"))
    context = iter(context)
    event, root = context.next()
    for event, elem in context:
        if event == 'start' and elem.tag == "hello":
            print("start report")
except SyntaxError, ParseError as exc:
    pass
except Exception
    pass
```

Comment: the except `error` could be different however, like malformed (missing last tag) xml will throw an error during `for` block with a `ParseError`